# Query MySQL to connect 2 databases

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: one hostgroup_host and the other one hostgroups. The hostgroups represents the names of all the host groups and has 3 important values (hostgroup_id, name and alias). The hostgroup_host makes the connection between the groups and the hosts and has two values (hostgroup_id and host_id).
Example:
`hostgroup_id = 1` and `host_id = 3` it means that host which id is number 3 belongs to hostgroup with `id = 1` (with a specific name).

I have this:

$name=$_POST['name'];
$alias=$_POST['alias'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$hostgroup=$_POST['hostgroup'];

mysql_connect('localhost:/usr/local/groundwork/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock', $username ,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO hosts (host_id, name, alias, address, hosttemplate_id) VALUES ('','$name','$alias','$address', '1');
INSERT INTO hostgroup_host (hostgroup_id, host_id) VALUES ((select hostgroup_id from hostgroups where name='$hostgroup'), (SELECT
host_id from hosts where name = '$name'))";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
?>

Why doesn't work?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, just join your insert statements:
something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (id,name,alias);
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (id,name);
```

the ; is seperating commands in my sql,
so basicly when you will run the query, both of the insert statements will be run.

Comment: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will only execute 1 query though (multiple queries are not supported), so you will have to execute every query in a separate call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, but just use more than one link resource.

```
$linka = mysql_connect('server1', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$linkb = mysql_connect('server2', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

Then use

```
$result = mysql_query('INSERT...', $linka);
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query('INSERT...', $linka);
```

But I fear I may have misunderstood your question completely...

Comment: grim imagine one page to add an host: i have 3 textboxes (name, alias and address) and a dropdown menu which lists all the groups available (the host being added is going to belong to one of the groups). After submit I have another php file which makes all those actions. I just want to know how can I pick the hostgroup_id associated to the name on the dropdown menu (the group name) and insert into hostgroup_host associated to the host id.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or wouldn't it just be better to have the hostgroup_id and the host_id as the option values in the dropdowns?

```
<select name="hosts">
  <option value="1">Host 1</option>
  ...
</select>

<select name="hostgroups">
  <option value="15">Host with 15 as ID</option>
  ...
</select>
```

then just insert the post values